# How to get Angular service by name programmatically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service

I have a string that contains the name of a service I need to inject into in one of my controllers programmatically.

```
function Ctrl() {
    var serviceName = '$myService';
    var service = ???
}
```

I am assuming it should be pretty easy to do something similar to:

```
function Ctrl($injector) {
    var serviceName = '$myService';
    var service = $injector.inject(serviceName);
}
```

I know I don't have the syntax correct but can someone give me the correct syntax?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can get a service like this:

`var myService = $injector.get('MyServiceName');`

Comment: I hate it when I miss something so simple but I appreciate it very much!